# Placeholder-Behaviour for Textbox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Is there any property for Textbox in Silverlight like placeholder in html input Tag?
I want to provide some hint to the user what this text box takes as input..
For Example:
When the page is loaded there is a string in TextBox like "search here..." and as soon the user clicks into the TextBox the string disappears and it appears again if the user didn't insert something as soon as the user click out this textbox.

Comment: what is a placeholder tag in html input? it is not so clear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it with a behavior:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2010/09/17/silverlight-watermark-textbox-behavior.aspx

Comment: great pretty simple...Thank you so much

Comment: Hey I have a problem - when I attached it to my TextBox and run the program it doesn't show the water mark unless and until I click on text box and again lost focus.. i don;t get it why it happens.. Can you please help me out with this.. Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

I made a slight modification/enhancement to Johan's watermark behavior class, because it doesn't account for when the textfield changes due to binding. (i.e. let's say you had:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding AccountNumber,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Behaviors:Placeholder Text="Enter Account #..." Foreground="Gray" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

And then in your view model:

```
    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get { return _accountNumber; }
        set { _accountNumber = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("AccountNumber");
        }
    }
```

Now the behavior updates the watermark if you do something like "AccountNumber = string.Empty" somewhere in your code:

```
public class Placeholder : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private bool _hasPlaceholder;
    private Brush _textBoxForeground;

    public String Text { get; set; }
    public Brush Foreground { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        _textBoxForeground = AssociatedObject.Foreground;

        base.OnAttached();
        if (Text != null)
            SetPlaceholderText();
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus += GotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += LostFocus;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += TextChanged;     
    }

    private void TextChanged(object sender, 
        TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AssociatedObject.Text) &&
            FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() != AssociatedObject)
        {
            if (Text != null)
                SetPlaceholderText();
        }
    }

    private void LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AssociatedObject.Text))
        {
            if (Text != null)
                SetPlaceholderText();
        }
    }

    private void GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_hasPlaceholder)
            RemovePlaceholderText();
    }

    private void RemovePlaceholderText()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Foreground = _textBoxForeground;
        AssociatedObject.Text = "";
        _hasPlaceholder = false;
    }

    private void SetPlaceholderText()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Foreground = Foreground;
        AssociatedObject.Text = Text;
        _hasPlaceholder = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= GotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= LostFocus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is the better solution when binding.

Comment: Note that this implementation is unfortunately a bit buggy. It will bind the `Description...` text into your data bound value, at least that was what happened to me (note: I am using a special behavior for delaying the binding, which could affect it - YMMV). It also will render pre-populated text with the placeholder color which is incorrect.

I am looking into another solution instead where I display a TextBlock on top of the other TextBox instead, which gets hidden when the TextBox receives focus.